# How to test application yml resource file settings that uses Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

For example, I have settings like code below which Spring Boot Actuator uses.

```
management:
  server:
    port: 60001
  security:
    enabled: false
```

And I found out that if I will write this setting with mistakes. For example (code below):

```
management:
  server:
    port: 60001
  security:
    enabled: fase # wrong typed a `false` word
```

Spring Boot will not do anything, and the application will have build successfully.

Comment: It depends on how code is implemented where the property is read from application yml. As long as your yml file is syntactically correct, application will built correctly (is exception is not thrown explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot will validate the data as long as **@ConfigurationProperties** exist in core. The problem is that your @ConfigurationProperties may not exist before or already deprecated in your spring boot version. 
[image]

Below is the comparison of `management.server` class with @ConfigurationProperties. 
Try to change the port with string and spring boot with validate the data.
[image]

Look also at **ManagementContextAutoConfiguration**.class if your using spring boot 2 you will see that it loads the class **ManagementServerProperties** and **WebEndpointProperties**

[image]

If you still needed to validate your yaml you can refer to [SnakeYAML](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml).